# How to show every topological space $X$, the counit map $|\text{Sing } X | \to X$ is a weak homotopy equivalence?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

I wonder how to show $|\text{Sing } X |$ and $X$ are  weak homotopy equivalent?

Comment: What is $|\text{Sing }X|$?

Comment: @Couchy311 Given any topological space $X$, one can associate a simplicial set Sing X , whose $n$-simplices are precisely the continuous maps $|\Delta^n |\to X$, where $|\Delta^n |$ iis the standard n-simplex.

Comment: @Couchy311 and |sing X| is the geometric realisation of sing X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Sorry for the notational difference. My $S$ is the OP’s Sing.

Suppose a space $A$ is homeomorphic to the geometric realization of some simplicial set $T$. Then maps from $A$ to $X$ are naturally in bijection with maps from $T$ to $SX$. Applying geometric realization to get a correspondingly map $A\to |SX|$, the definition of adjunction now implies that every map $A$ to $X$ factors canonically through the canonical map $|SX|\to X$.

In particular, this works when $A$ is a sphere, showing the induced map on homotopy groups is surjective, or when $A=S^n\wedge I_+$ is the space representing basepoint-fixed homotopies of maps from $S^n$, showing that the induced map is injective.

Comment: Does the case $A=S^n\wedge I_+$ also prove the subjectivity?

Comment: @Danny Sure, if you like. Look at a sphere in $X$ as a  constant homotopy, lift to $|SX|$, then restrict to a sphere in there.